# Layout Issues Wordpress and WPBakery

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I am trying to align an image Block and a Text block in Wordpress using WPBakery addon. I want the image to take up half the area and same with the Text block. Can anyone explain to me how to do this?

[image: how it currently looks]

[image: How I want it to look]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Looks like either the image has `margin` or the wrapper div has `padding`, add the code for that part

Answer (score 0):

Use css to change the position,
in my case we use:

```
.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;,
    padding-left: 15px;,
    padding-right: 15px;,
    width: 100%;,
}
```

Remove (,) from the code.